# Setting a system environment variable from a Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

Is it possible to set a environment variable at the system level from a command prompt in Windows 7 (or even XP for that matter). I am running from an elevated command prompt.

When I use the `set` command (`set name=value`), the environment variable seems to be only valid for the session of the command prompt.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

The XP Support Tools (which can be installed from your XP CD) come with a program called `setx.exe`:

```
C:\Program Files\Support Tools>setx /?

SETX: This program is used to set values in the environment
of the machine or currently logged on user using one of three modes.

1) Command Line Mode: setx variable value [-m]
   Optional Switches:
    -m  Set value in the Machine environment. Default is User.

...
For more information and example use: SETX -i
```

I think Windows 7 actually comes with `setx` as part of a standard install.

Comment: Windows 7 (maybe Vista already) has setx standard, with a minor change? there is no `-i` flag and just running `setx /?` displays all help + examples

Comment: Remember you can always check to see if you have this program on your path by typing `where` and then the name of the program (so in this case `where setx.exe` in testing this on a Server 2008 and Server 2008SP2 box I found that in both cases it existed at `%windir%\System32\setx.exe`

Comment: @stijn - The Win7 version also officially changed the flag introducer from `-` to the forward slash `/`. However, it looks like the `-` version still works.

Comment: There seems to be a 1024 length limit to the setx variable content

Comment: The setx provided by XP SP2 Support Tools requires forward slash `/` and the dash `-` does not work. `setx variable value /m`

Answer (score 169):

Simple example for how to set JAVA_HOME with `setx.exe` in command line:

```
setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_04"
```

This will set environment variable "JAVA_HOME" for current user. If you want to set a variable for all users, you have to use option "/m" (or -m, prior to Windows 7).

Here is an example:

```
setx /m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_04"
```

**Note**: you have to execute this command as Administrator.

**Note**: Make sure to run the command *setx* from an **command-line Admin window**

Comment: also note that some tools don't like spaces in JAVA_HOME so it's worth using `Progra~1` like so:


 `setx /M JAVA_HOME "C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_09"`

Answer (score 26):

If you set a variable via SETX, you cannot use this variable or its changes immediately. You have to restart the processes that want to use it.

**Use the following sequence to directly set it in the setting process too** (works for me perfectly in scripts that do some init stuff after setting global variables)**:**

```
SET XYZ=test
SETX XYZ test
```

Answer (score 3):

[SetX](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) is the command that you'll need in most of the cases.Though its possible to use [REG](https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) or [REGEDIT](https://ss64.com/nt/regedit.html)

Using registry editing commands you can avoid some of the restrictions of the SetX command - different data types, variables containing `=` in their name and so on.

```
@echo off

:: requires admin elevated permissions
::setting system variable
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v MyVar /D MyVal
::expandable variable
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /T REG_EXPAND_SZ /v MyVar /D MyVal


:: does not require admin permissions
::setting user variable
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment" /v =C: /D "C:\\test"
```

REG is the pure registry client but its possible also to import the data with REGEDIT though it allows using only hard coded values (or generation of a temp files). The example here is a hybrid file that contains both batch code and registry data (should be saved as `.bat` - mind that in batch `;` are ignored as delimiters while they are used as comments in `.reg` files):

```
REGEDIT4

; @ECHO OFF
; CLS
; REGEDIT.EXE /S "%~f0"
; EXIT

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment]
"SystemVariable"="GlobalValue"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment]
"UserVariable"="SomeValue"
```

Answer (score 2):

For XP, I used a (free/donateware) tool called "RAPIDEE" (Rapid Environment Editor), but SETX is definitely sufficient for Win 7 (I did not know about this before).

Answer (score 2):

System variables can be set through CMD and registry 
For ex. **reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v PATH**

All the commonly used CMD codes and system variables are given here: [Set Windows system environment variables using CMD](http://www.mindxmaster.com/2017/03/modify-add-windows-system-environment-variables.html).

Open CMD and type **Set**

You will get all the values of system variable.

Type **set java** to know the path details of java installed on your window OS.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you would need to delete a variable, you could use SETENV from Vincent Fatica available at http://barnyard.syr.edu/~vefatica.
Not exactly recent ('98) but still working on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: setx allows you to delete also by setting the value to blank

Comment: @SteveLloyd  and others who find this: I found that `setx` only let me do that when I ran it in `cmd.exe` and not when run in powershell fyi