# rake --tasks full description (not cut)

Tags: ruby, rake

Maybe it's one of those code 18,

but when I run **rake -T** on my Rakefile, the long descriptions of my tasks are always cut.
Is there any way to display the full description without having to make the desc shorter?

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The format is slightly different (description starts on the next line instead of as a comment on the current line), but this will give you the full descriptions:

```
rake -D
```

Also, if you really want the other format, you can pipe the output to `cat` instead:

```
rake -T | cat
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I never saw that -D in --help... and I really like the cat command. I use git bash on windows so i'm not that familiar with all the combos...

Answer (score 7):

> -D, --describe [PATTERN]  Describe the tasks (matching optional
>   PATTERN), then exit.

`rake -D`

Comment: Thanks you answer is good but the other one is a bit more complete... Normally I would have accepted it. I  just can't accept both and had to make a choice.

Answer (score 2):

Three solutions:

1) You may define your own '-T'

```
task :longT do
  app = Rake.application
  app.tasks.each{|task|
    puts "%-20s  # %s" % [task.name, task.comment] if task.comment
  }
end
```

2) fool, there is no tty:

```
Rake.application.tty_output= false
```

3) Modify a rake command

```
module Rake
  class Application
    def truncate_output?
      #tty_output? || ENV['RAKE_COLUMNS']
      false
    end
  end
end
```

I would recommend version 2)

(Tested with rake-0.8.7)

Answer (score 2):

There's an environment variable you can set:

```
export RAKE_COLUMNS=200
```

Comment: [See this question for setting the variable on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803581/setting-a-system-environment-variable-from-a-windows-batch-file)