# installing pik in system path in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, pik

I just installed pik (ruby version control) on my windows machine at work ( to C:\bin ), but it said that it's not installed in the system path, that I'll have to add it. I don't often use a windows machine. Can anyone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setting Path on Windows**

For Windows XP:

1. Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced
2. Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.
3. In the Edit windows, modify PATH. If you do not have the item PATH, you may select to add a new variable and add PATH as the name and the location of the class as the value.
4. Close the window.

For Windows Vista:

1. Right click “My Computer” icon
2. Choose “Properties” from context menu
3. Click “Advanced” tab (“Advanced system settings” link in Vista)
4. In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the location of the class to the value for PATH. If you do not have the item PATH, you may select to add a new variable and add PATH as the name and the location of the class as the value.

[(source)](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

In Windows 7 it is the same as in Vista, but there is also an option to set it from command line using `setx` program, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803581/setting-a-system-environment-variable-from-a-windows-batch-file).