# Ruby Version 1.9.3p392 Causing Errors with gem 'monbon'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, patch, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-2.0

The Ruby Version set on my **windows** machine is:
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32]

I have tried running the ruby installer for Ruby 2.0.0 but cannot seem to get it to replace the 1.9.3p392.

Now I am working in a tutorial that requires the gem 'monbon' - but when I run bundle on a new app, I get the message:

Could not find gem 'monbon' (= 0.0.6) x86-mingw32' in the gems available on this machine.

1. Is the patch on the Ruby causing this error and why?
2. What are some steps I can take to just run Ruby 1.9.3 or 2.0.0?

   3. Any further code or screen shots I can take to help diagnose issue?

**EDIT TO ADD SOLUTION:**

1. I was able to install Pik 
   (https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) 
   by following this tutorial 
   (http://puneetpandey.com/tag/how-to-install-and-configure-pik-on-windows/) 
   and solving an error by this stack overflow questions ([installing pik in system path in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273110/installing-pik-in-system-path-in-windows))
2. Then I installed Ruby 2.0.0 and also the exact Ruby version and patch from the tutorial using Pik.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this 'strange patch' is perfectly normal and expected.  It tells you the patchlevel that has been applied to your ruby 1.9.3 installation.  And *patches are good* - they generally are used to fix security and stability issues.

Secondly, the [i386-mingw32] is there to let you know that you are using the Windows flavor (or 'i386-mingw32' flavor to be more correct) of ruby.  This is important, because not all gems necessarily support all OS's without some tweaking.  Many of them need to be compiled, and the instructions for doing so can differ from OS to OS.  Now on to your list:

1. The strange patch is not causing the error.
2. The steps you can take to run the correct Ruby are - install pik.  It lets you choose the right version of ruby whenever you want.  And it lets you set the default version when you don't want to think about it.
3. Nothing to diagnose, everything is running as expected.  The gem can't be found for the i386-mingw32 ruby flavor.  Check with your 'monbon' gem author to see if and how this can be resolved.

Comment: Thank you - I appreciate getting direction on what is and isn't normal as I'm learning! I'll look into pik and then go back to the tutorial when I understand the versions a little better!

Comment: @Meeka: Good luck with that.  For reference, [pik](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/pik/) is the Windows alternative to RVM (which only supports *nix and OSX).