# batch file - setting the user input to the system variable path

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I want the user to input the path of the bin directory and then store that path to system variable path

i tried this

```
 set /p path = Please specify the path to the bin folder
 echo Path is set to = %path%
```

does not seems to work

Basically i want the user to enter the path and that entered path gets permanently stored in the system variable 'path' hope i am more clear now

Comment: Define 'does not work'...

Answer (score 1):

You may get help from the answer of this question: [Setting a system environment variable from a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803581/setting-a-system-environment-variable-from-a-windows-batch-file)

It says you should use `setx`

Comment: problem with setx is, we have 2 PATH variables: one system wide & one user's own. I don't want to add only to user's local `path` variable.

Comment: @anishsane  Check out the `/M` option for `setx /?`.  It will do what you want.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: When we read PATH variable, it's concatenated version of both PATH variables. I want to set `new_user_path=old_user_path;my_dir` NOT `new_user_path=old_path;my_dir`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces. The `set` command doesn't trim, so the input is actually stored in a variable named `path<space>`.

This is something you should be able to spot easily if you call `set` without parameters. You will see an extra variable that has this extra space.

BUT NOTE: `path` is already an existing variable, containing the search path for the command session. You'd better use a different name altogether if you don't want to overwrite that variable.

Comment: and how do i append the user entered path to the system path variab;e

Comment: `set path=%path%;%yourtemporaryvariable%`

Comment: much easy i was trying with registries and all

Comment: Hmm. I think this is not persistent. That is, if your command session closes, the value will be gone. I see you added a paragraph about persistency to your question that wasn't there before.

Comment: With `setx` you should be able to make it persistent, I think, but there's another limit. If I run `setx path="%path%;c:\added\path" \m`, I get an error "ERROR: Length of the command line argument should not exceed 255 characters". And that is a problem, since you %path% variable is likely to be longer (it is on my PC). Long story short: Batch is not the right place to modify this variable. Also, you would need administrator rights for your script.