# Window add Java to Path

Tags: java, windows, path

I used to use My Computer -> Environment variables to set up PATH for Java, but where can I find the same in Windows 8?

Answer (score 21):

Click:

> Windows-Key

Type: Control Panel

In the control panel search box, enter:

> path

Select

> Edit environment variables for your account

or

> Edit the system environment variables

as needed.

The environment variable dialog itself is very similar to the one under previous versions of Windows.

Comment: this id good... any way to do this from the command prompt? I want to create a batch file to do this. Thanks!

Comment: @frenetix: Yes see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803581/setting-a-system-environment-variable-from-a-windows-batch-file

Answer (score 4):

Set Environment variable using Command Prompt in easy two steps:

Example of windows SET command:

**Step 1.** Print the PATH environment variable

```
C:\>echo %PATH%
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
```

**Step 2.** Add one variable to path ( For example : Java SDK )

```
// => Path for JDK 8 - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin
C:\>set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin
```

**Verify the Change**

```
C:\>echo %PATH%
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin
```