# Perl in Windows 8

Tags: windows, perl, windows-8

I am trying to get Strawberry perl running on my windows 8 machine.  This is my first attempt ever to use perl and I am going through the readme file to try and get it up and running. At the moment i have got as far as typing

```
c:\>perl
```

and i get access denied message. Am i misunderstanding the readme or do i need to make some further adjustments to get it to work?

The instrustions for the readme are

```
1. run any perl script by launching

 c:\> perl c:\path\to\script.pl
```

i have also tried

```
c:\>perl c:\perls\ex1.pl
```

where perls is the folder on C: in which the script ex1 is located.  Also get `access denied` message.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Win8 (stuck in XPland) but this sounds like permissions problem with your installation. I would recommend posting on SuperUser, possibly

Comment: For starters, find the directory where you installed Perl (say, "c:\program files\strawberry\bin\" and run Perl as full path: "c:\program files\strawberry\bin\perl c:\perls\ex1.pl". If that works, you will simply need to add Perl's directory to `PATH` variable

Comment: For permissions, see: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-open-a-file-if-i-get-an-access-denied-message

Comment: okay that seems to have done the trick.  Only catch was that there is also a folder named perls from the install which i put directly on C: so it ended up being c:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl

Comment: Did you type `c:>perl` like you said? Because that is a command `c:` with a redirection `>` to a file `perl`, which on my system gives the exact error `Access denied`.

Comment: Try and type `perl -e "print 'Hello world'"` in a cmd shell and see if that works as expected.

Comment: That worked.  Thank you guys, now for endless hours of fun laying with perl.

Comment: @CSnewb - which one worked? using full path?

Comment: @DVK I suspect he tried typing the prompt: `c:>perl`.

Comment: @TLP, Good catch! Make it an answer.

Comment: @TLP - unless I'm completely out of my mind, wouldn't typing that simply execute "C:" command to switch current directory to the C: drive's active directory, and redirect the (empty) output into a file called "perl"? **UPDATE**: See proof test: http://pastebin.com/jZVJYKu2

Comment: @DVK It seems that the folder `c:\ ` is protected, at least on my system. So that would explain things. On the other hand, if you have installed perl under `c:\perl`, it would not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be either the fact that Perl isn't in your `PATH`, or permissions issue.

---

If it's the `PATH`, to troubleshoot and fix:

- Find the directory where you installed Perl (say, `"c:\program files\strawberry\perl\bin\"` as an example)
- Run Perl as full path: `"c:\program files\strawberry\perl\bin\perl c:\perls\ex1.pl".
- If that works, you will simply need to add Perl's directory to PATH variable, so that running "perl" without a path will search for it in that directory. To do that, here are the references:

  - [Window add Java to Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224756/window-8-add-java-to-path)
  - https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them
  - http://www.itechtics.com/customize-windows-environment-variables/

---

If it's permissions, here's a reference: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-open-a-file-if-i-get-an-access-denied-message

Answer (score 1):

Posting comment as answer.

The command

```
c:\>perl
```

in the windows cmd shell is an instruction to redirect the output of the command `c:\` to a file named `perl`. The `>` character is the one that does that.

I was going to say that it fails because you probably have a directory named `perl` there, but I notice on my system that it fails even though I have no such directory.

The problem is that the readme had included the prompt in their sample command. The default prompt in windows cmd looks like that: `C:\>` So, like I mentioned in the comments, the command you need to run perl is simply `perl`. For example:

```
perl -e "print 'Hello world!'"
```