# javac is not recognized as an internal or external command in windows 7

Tags: java, windows

I have set JAVA_HOME and PATH variable.

JAVA_HOME looks like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
```

PATH looks like this:

```
    %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;

    "C:\Program Files\nodejs\" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command";C:\mongodb\bin;"C:\Program Files\cURL\bin" ;C:\Python34\python.exe; 

"%JAVA_HOME%/bin" ;
```

Yet it can not find any of the java commands like javac or java,

User Path variable:

```
 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\; C:\Users\dev4\AppData\Roaming\npm; C:\mongodb\bin; " %JAVA_HOME%\bin\" ; "%ANT_HOME%\bin\" ;
```

System path variable:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\; C:\Program Files\nodejs\ ; C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\mongodb\bin;C:\Program Files\cURL\bin ;C:\Python34\python.exe; %JAVA_HOME%\bin\;
```

Despite npm command is not working either.

These have been working before but since I was trying to set path for java , al of them have stopped working

Comment: possible duplicate of [Window 8 add Java to Path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224756/window-8-add-java-to-path)

Comment: "%JAVA_HOME%/bin" or "%JAVA_HOME%\bin" ?

Comment: I don't see how that changes anything. The path to the binaries is still the same format right?

Comment: Unix/Linux uses forward slash, Windows uses backward slash.

Answer (score 4):

Please use `\` **backslash** not `/` **forward slash** That is the issue in your Path setup

[image]

**EDIT :-**

1. Right-click the My Computer icon on your desktop and select Properties.
2. Click Advanced system settings link.
3. Click the Advanced tab.
4. Click the Environment Variables button.
5. Under System Variables, click New.
6. Enter the variable name as `JAVA_HOME`
   Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java Development Kit as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60`
7. Now make entry for `Path` variable shown above image

Comment: I did. IT did not help either.

Comment: Still same issue ? How you checked your Java Path set or Not? If your command prompt open when you doing entry in environment variables then please close command prompt and try again..

Comment: Please check the update. Yes, I did close and reopen it

Comment: Why you put another `\  backslash` after  `bin`? same you did for ANT Path also why you added double quotes `" "` ? Did you checked my answer?

Comment: I had added just to check if it works that way. It did not. I had tried it both ways. None of them worked

Comment: @SimranKaur if you will try wrong way it never worked

Answer (score 2):

Don't do what I did and sit there wondering for an hour why the path isn't changing in your windows.

Change the Variable...

> **THEN RESTART YOUR PC**

An hour I will never get back lost to not doing the first thing you should try.

Answer (score -1):

In my system, User variable path is as below

> ```
> C:\apache-ant-1.9.5\bin;E:\Android\platform-tools;E:\Android\tools;C:\Users\M\AppData\Roaming\npm
> ```

And my system path variable is

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\

JAVA_HOME is

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45

Hope this helps.