# Run command to go to user's documents folder (similar to %appdata%)?

Tags: windows, userappdatapath

Putting %appdata% into the run window will open up the Appdata folder, but what is the command to open the User's Documents folder, even when someone else logs in? I thought it was something like %userdir%, but I can not find out what it is. Not sure what to search for in Google either so I am at a loss.

Comment: Did you want the path to a specific user's documents when someone logs in, or their own(i.e. I'm logged in as John, but I want a variable to access Jane's documents, or I am John I want to access my own Documents)?

Comment: I am John I want to access my own Documents. And then I am Jane I want to open my own Documents.

Comment: Updated code in my answer. Should be what you need. Unless you need to create an alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no environment variable for this. You'll need to set one. Here's a list of all Windows default environment variables:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true

<sup>*This is for XP, but should be the same for newer versions of Windows</sup>

**For a single terminal session**, you can just use

```
set USERDOCS=%USERPROFILE%\Documents
```

**For all terminal sessions**, you'll need to set a system environment variable. You can do this using the GUI or using `setx -m USERDOCS %USERPROFILE\Documents`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803581/setting-a-system-environment-variable-from-a-windows-batch-file).

The command to make this happen would be

`explorer %USERDOCS%`

But if you wanted to make an alias to that (i.e. a `openuserdocs` command), I can update and explain.

Comment: %USERPROFILE% is what I was looking for! I use VBA, so I could just use 'strPath = "%USERPROFILE%\Documents"' to save files to be used by one user only.