# Parameters passed to jenkins job are not updated on slave machine

Tags: python, jenkins, environment-variables, hudson

So, I have got a Jenkins job which is a parameterized build. I allow the users to select one of the environments where they want to execute the build. This parameter is stored in variable ${my_env}. Then I use "Execute Windows Batch Command" component in Job's configuration to execute the following command :

> setx /M envi %my_env%

This allows me to set the environment variable on my windows slave machine as envi=my_env.
Now I have my project on this slave machine which is python based, and I fetch the environment variable in my project using os.environ['envi'] and execute the code further accordingly based on the value of 'envi'.
Problem is when I first execute this job, it is all fine. It fetches the correct value of environment variable 'envi' and execute the correct code as per the environment selected. But when I execute it second time choosing the different environment from build parameters, it does not update in my project and it picks the old value of environment variable 'envi'. I have verified that the actual value of environment is updated using the Setx command, but my python project still fetches the old value. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the working of `setx` and `set` variables in windows, `setx` will update the value permanently but not make it available immediately. `set` will make it available immediately but not permanent. So you have to use both to work immediately. So code will be like :

```
SET XYZ=<value>
SETX /M XYZ <value>
```

This will make XYZ value to be set in this session and also makes it permanent. I am adding some useful links to study for yourself. Hope this helps.

1. https://superuser.com/a/916652/652923
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777506/5003256
3. https://superuser.com/a/176788/652923