# Declare a variable using system("set x= "); in C++

Tags: c++, batch-file, variables

I am a beginner in learning C++ and I have a lot of experience in making batch files. I found the command 'system("command");' which preforms a single CMD command. There is one problem with it which is that we cannot declare a variable.

lets say we have this code in a batch file:

```
@echo off
set x= hi
echo %x%
pause
```

the above code will provide the message hi and pause.

when i tried to rewrite it in C++, it will look something like

```
int main()
{
    system("set x=hi");
    system("echo %x%");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

this will only will print %x% instead of hi.
How can I declare a variable and use it? I thought maybe there is a way to write multiple commands in one system(""); but i don't know how. Thanks

Edit: For those who are curious why I want to do this, I want to convert some of the programs i made to work as a part of c++ program. I've worked on batch files for years and I made many many programs. It will be helpful if i can implement them here.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? Writing batch commands in C++ is often times the wrong approach to problems.

Comment: You're setting variable value in a temporary child process (in a `cmd` that is spawned for every `system()` call). I think you need to use `setx` instead -- it will modify global variable value, not a private value of temporary child. More info can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803581/setting-a-system-environment-variable-from-a-windows-batch-file

Comment: @UnholySheep I want to convert some of the programs i made to work as a part of c++ program. I've worked on batch files for years and I made many many programs. It will be helpful if i can implement them here.

Comment: This is an interesting, non-trivial question. It is quite probable that fundamentally different approaches are better suited to solve the OP's actual (unknown) problem, but the question as it stands is perfectly valid.

Comment: @EvilDEvil It's likely that you are better off with some scripting language if you want to "glue" existing batch files together. And consider calling batch scripts *as files* as I suggested in my edited answer, rather than calling `system` with real commands. Data which you would hold in DOS variables could come from command line arguments to your (C++ or other) program.

Comment: @EvilDEvil By the way, it is better to add additional information to the question proper, not as comments.

Comment: You have a different definition of "convert" than me - for me "converting" code would imply that I rewrite it from scratch using the facilities and paradigms of the new language. You are trying to "glue" code written in one language into a different language (which is something I would not recommend except in very, very specific scenarios)

Comment: You forgot a basic point in your question. If you have any code _in a Batch file_, you did _NOT_ execute such a code _via the commands themselves_; you just execute **the Batch file**! If you want to do the same in C++ just _create a Batch file_ and then execute it via `system` call. If you really want to solve this problem in this way, you need to find a way to execute several individual Batch commands with no Batch file and not in a `cmd.exe` session. After that, just use the same method in your C++ program... **`:/`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start a new command shell with every `system` call; variables you declare exist only in that command shell.

Unfortunately I was not able to find out how to use variables in `system` calls directly.<sup>1</sup>

Furtunately though, [@aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) knew the answer and posted it as comment (thanks!). The reason `set a=abc && echo %a%` does not work (also not when you type it in a console) is that `%a%` is evaluated *when the command is parsed*, that is, before the `set` command has been executed. At that point the variable is not set. Calling `cmd` with "delayed expansion" enabled switches the evaluation time to *execution time*; when the `echo` is encountered the variable is defined and will be printed.

The option to activate delayed evaluation is `/V`. `cmd /?` prints the following:

> /V:ON   Enable delayed environment variable expansion using ! as the
>           delimiter. For example, /V:ON would allow !var! to expand the
>           variable var at execution time.  The var syntax expands variables
>           at input time, which is quite a different thing when inside of a FOR
>           loop.

So this will work:

```
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
  system("cmd /V:ON /C set a=abcd ^&^& echo !a!");
  return 0;
}
```

Another solution could be to let your program create a temporary batch file and then execute that file in a single trivial `system` command. The strategy to move complicated scripts in files is recommended in general for Windows because it avoids command line parsing by `cmd` which is notoriously hard to get right ([here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/twistylittlepassagesallalike/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way/) is a Microsoft blog diving into the details).

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ofstream batchfile{ "tmpbatchfile.bat" };

  batchfile << "set x=abc\n";
  batchfile << "echo %x%\n";
  batchfile << "pause\n";

  system("tmpbatchfile.bat");

  return 0;
}
```

Note that the `system` call appears to return before the command has finished. This makes it impossible to delete the temporary file.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>One should think that passing a string with more than one command — multi-line or `&&`-chained — would do the trick, but I cannot get it to work.</sub>

For example `system("echo abc && echo ****");` works; but `system("set a=abc && echo %a%");` does not (it prints a literal `%a%`).

Answer (score -1):

> I thought maybe there is a way to write multiple commands in one
>   system(""); but i don't know how.

The string passed to [`system`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) will get passed on to the underlying shell as a single command. It is implementation-defined (and highly system-specific) what behavior that string will trigger on the underlying shell.

In your concrete case of invoking the standard `cmd` shell on Windows, it is not possible to reproduce the exact behavior of your example batch script with a simple `system` call.

Unlike a batch script, where each command gets executed in the same interpreter context, the three distinct `system` calls from your second example each create a new context. So by the time you execute the second `system` call, the state set by the first call (ie. the value of the environment variable `x`) has already been lost.

Unfortunately, it is also not possible to directly combine arbitrary batch commands into a single `system` call.

Comment: I understand why it doesn't work, what I need here is a work around for this problem.

Comment: @EvilDEvil: There isn't one. That's what ComicSansMS is saying. You should instead approach the problem in a more appropriate way.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit maybe we can use other commands other than system() to solve the problem

Comment: @EvilDEvil Your question as it stands currently is too unspecific to provide you with a workaround. If you could clarify what exactly it is you are trying to achieve here, maybe we could provide a solution that is more helpful.

Comment: @ComicSansMS I am trying to make a variable and use it in cmd commands.

Comment: Actually, see @aschipfl comment on the other answer :)

Comment: "I need to do <thing>." "You can't do <thing>." "Is there a workaround?" "What do you want to do?" "I want to do <thing>". This won't work, @EvilDEvil!

Comment: Presumably you want to use that variable and commands to achieve some goal. What is that goal?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit check my comment under the question

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The OP said "I cannot do <thing>", which is different from "I need to do <thing>" (it's better because it doesn't imply that there are no other ways). And then the answer "You can't do <thing>" is wrong; the answer is "use cmd /V and ! instead of %".

Comment: @EvilDEvil: Please edit clarifications into the question itself.

Comment: I believe this answer was proven as incorrect, as determine by @aschipl in a comment on the other answer, care to update your answer based on this?